# Xamarin/XCode register provisioning profile error

Tags: xcode, xamarin, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have the following problem. I'm creating Xamarin iOS application(by vs for max 2017) and during a building I have this error:

> No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing
> identities.

As far as I can understand the solution of this problem is connected with creating provisioning profile by xCode. But when I try to generate provisioning profile(with name testtesyui) by xCode I see this error:

> Failed to create provisioning profile.
> There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website.
> Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.
>
> No profiles for 'testtesyui' were found
> Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'testtesyui'.

I don't have any real iOS device and I'm planning to use iOS emulator.
Below, I listed screnshoots from xCode ui(I've hid personal data):
[xCode account settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQFWd.jpg),
[xCode general settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXeep.jpg)

Could some one help with this problem? Please let me know if you need more details.
Thanks.

**Updating**:
I opened info.plist file in vs for mac and I saw the following:
[info.plist content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhycT.jpg).
I've tried to sign in in my apple account, but in the end I saw this message:
[signin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Pou.jpg). As a result, I still cannot select my team.

Could you please give advice where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my problem was in a solution configuration. By some reason, I tryed to build my application in Debug|iPhone mode, not in Debug|iPhoneSimulator mode. 
When I switched to Debug|iPhoneSimulator mode, then the build works fine.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to enable automatic signing to work with simulator

Once you’ve ensured you have an Apple ID connected to Visual Studio for Mac, you’re ready to enable Automatic Signing

**Steps**

1. In your iOS project, open the `Info.plist` file. In the `Signing section`, select your team from the Team dropdown:
2. Then, select the Automatically manage signing  checkbox.

More Info [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/even-easier-ios-app-provisioning-visual-studio-mac/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wrote my updating in original message.